# Nginx location directive not adhering to index

Tags: nginx, php

I have a webserver, with two PHP applications. 
One (WordPress) is living in the root, and another is living in a /forums location directive. 
In the /forums location I have to explicitly call php files for it to load. It does not automatically respect the index rule, set in the vhost.

What am I doing wrong?

```
root /www/wordpress;
index index.php;

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
location /forums {
  alias /www/forums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index` directive operates on URIs that end with `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for more.

You explicitly add a trailing `/` with your `$uri/` clause in the `try_files` statement in the `location /` block. Which is missing from your `location /forums` block.

You should use `root` instead of `alias` where the final path segments are the same. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Try:

```
location /forums {
    root /www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for `try_files` syntax.